# How can I properly get the rest of this specific division in PHP?

Tags: php, function, math, division

I have this function.

```
public function handleaddMinutes(int $addedMinutes): void {
        $newMinutes = $this->getMinutes() + $addedMinutes;
        if($newMinutes > 60) {
            $hours = round($newMinutes / 60, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
            $this->addHour($hours);
            // TODO 
        }
        $this->addMinutes($newMinutes); //TODO
    }
```

If the minutes are over `60`, it should add an hour and the rest should be added as minutes. So, let's say I call the function with `125` minutes. The function should now use `$this->addHour()` to add `2 hours` and `$this->addMinutes()`to add `25 minutes`.
How can I achieve this? I tried using the code below and that would probably work to add the hours but how could I **add the rest as minutes?**

Comment: `$newMinutes = $newMinutes % 60;`

Comment: fyi, 125 minutes are not two hours + 25 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modulo operator `%` will give your rest of minutes:

```
public function handleaddMinutes(int $addedMinutes): void {
    $newMinutes = $this->getMinutes() + $addedMinutes;
    if($newMinutes > 60) {
        $hours = round($newMinutes / 60, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
        $this->addHour($hours);
        // TODO 
    }
    $this->addMinutes($newMinutes % 60);
}
```